# Blazor WASM: does it violate best practices to have a state container manage API calls?

Tags: c#, blazor, state, webassembly

In Blazor WASM, say you have a state container that manages a list of Things. This state container is injected into multiple Razor Components throughout the application. Is it bad to, instead of responding to the state container being unitialized and calling the appropriate API from each component, to just request the list of the Things from the state container, and if the list of Things is not initialized, the state container itself calls the appropriate API to fetch them? Something like:

```
    public class ThingState
    {
        private IEnumerable<Thing> Things { get; set; }

        public async IEnumerable<Thing> GetThings()
        {
            if (Things == null)
            {
                Things = await Http.GetFromJsonAsync<IEnumerable<Thing>>("ThingsAPI");
                NotifyStateChanged();
            }

            return Things;
        }

        public event Action OnChange;

        private void NotifyStateChanged() => OnChange?.Invoke();

    }
```

Samples I have seen generally manage this at the razor component, but that seems duplicative if there are multiple components that use the same state container. Is this a bad way to implement this?

Comment: @Jesse ```Things``` is private so it would not be accessible externally other than via ```GetThings()```. I neglected the () at ```GetThings``` to indicate it is a method, updated that signature.

Comment: Sorry should of looked more carefully, but then how do you update `Things`?

Comment: Probably extend with a ```SetThing()``` method. Is it desirable to be able to update ```Things``` directly? If multiple components are using it via DI, they may have different requirements or need different ```Thing```s, which it seems like could compromise the requirements of other consumers of ```ThingState``` if, for example ```Things``` is set/updated with an incomplete set.

Comment: Really depends on your use case. Right now `Things` is an `IEnumerable` so you are limited on what you can do with it. `they may have different requirements or need different Things` I think the point you bring up starts to lead you to the answer to your question.